# jQuery (kendo) and .NET Web Service (asmx) and Json issues... Help needed

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web-services, kendo-ui

First of all, it did a lot of research on the subject and could not find answers or complete examples. I do not have a lot of experience with jquery, so I'm looking for a simple sample of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I want to have a Web Service (asmx) return a json that I can use to populate grids, comboboxes, autocompletes and etc. I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and here is what I got, or what my goal is:

**ASMX**:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

[ScriptService]
public class Services : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<Preceptor> SearchPrecetor()
    {
        List<Preceptor> myPreceptorList = new List<Preceptor>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Preceptor myPreceptor = new Preceptor();
            myPreceptor.Id = i;
            myPreceptor.Name = "Name" + i.ToString();
            myPreceptorList.Add(myPreceptor);

        }


        return myPreceptorList;
    }

    public class Preceptor {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#acPreceptors").kendoAutoComplete({
            minLength: 3,
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                transport: {
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    read: "../Services/Services.asmx/SearchPrecetor"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the **ERROR** I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'slice'
```

My guess is that there is still something wrong with the whole process, and the json is not getting to the client correctly. Again, I dont have a lot of experience with jquery, and would really appreciate a simple yet complete example of how to do this.

Any thoughts, links, code, fixes would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What is debugger saying, what file, line...

Comment: Thanks for replying... It is in the kendo.web.js and the following line: that._pristine = isPlainObject(data) ? $.extend(true, {}, data) : data.slice(0);

Comment: Can you post the full contents of the response you're getting back from the service?

Comment: I get an object with two properties... Message and the StackTrace. The message is: invalid JSON primitive: Take. And the StackTrace seems to be the calls made at the server side (C#). So I'd say that the call to the webservice is not sending the correct information.

Comment: This is the request payload: take=20&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=20&filter%5Blogic%5D=and&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=asd&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=startswith&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=Name&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BignoreCase%5D=true

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... I'm now getting the right information from the web service... BUTTTTT... it is coming in XML format, so Kendo won't read it or display anything (I picked the response through a debugger)

Answer (score 2):

When I use a .asmx service, I have to add the following in the datasource...

```
schema: {
data: "d", // ASMX services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. Specify how to get the result.
model: ....etc...
},
```

For example, my basic datasource is...

```
var sharableDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    data: "d", // ASMX services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. Specify how to get the result.
                    model: {    // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            Id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            ... and so forth .....
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true, 
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "sMyService.asmx/getList", //specify the URL which data should return the records.
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
                        type: "POST", //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for ASMX
                        data: { Id: 5 }
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                        if (operation != "read") {
                            // web service method parameters need to be send as JSON. 
                            return JSON.stringify({ myItems: data.models })
                        } else {
                            return JSON.stringify(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

My web service function...  (code to create array of items removed)

```
    <WebMethod> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)> _
Public Function getList(ByVal Id As Integer) As cDetail()
    Dim items As New List(Of cDetail)
    Return items.ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In the trasport of your datasource use this.

```
transport: {
    read: {
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Services/Services.asmx/SearchPrecetor"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But now I'm getting something different, do you have any idea of what it could be? Error: Invalid JSON primitive: take.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the docs http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/getting-started/web/autocomplete/overview#using-the-kendo-ui-web-datasource-to-bind-to-jsonp, it is all there.

I believe it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#acPreceptors").kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            transport: {
                read: {
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "../Services/Services.asmx/SearchPrecetor"
              }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Notice **read** object.

Comment: Thanks for your response! You were correct. But now I'm getting something different, do have any idea of what it could be? Error: Invalid JSON primitive: take.

Comment: Is your webservice returning valid json? Check that with some json validator.

Comment: It is, because I tried consuming the service with $.ajax and was able to get the object back just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those who replied. I indeed had screwed up at first with the syntax.

A lot of other problems appeared after that and here are the solutions I found for each:

(I'm hoping this can be useful to someone else in the future)

**In order for a ASMX Web Service to return JSON**

Web Service method must have:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

The request must contain:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
type: "POST"
```

**In order for parameters to be properly passed to the request**

```
parameterMap: function() {
   return kendo.stringify({ ParamName: $('#myTextBox').val() });
}
```

For some reason the Web Service will return the request inside a "d" object. Keep that in mind.

Always use a profiler to watch your requests and resposes.

I hope this helps.